# How to clear session in JQUery?

Tags: jquery

I have a session which I am setting in JQuery on some button click.

```
'<%Session["showHideFlagValue"] = "' + showSession + '"; %>';
```

I want to clear or remove this session on the other button click in JQuery.

Can someone help on this?

Comment: -1 because you need to read first about what is `<%` and `%>` things are... To start with they are not any way near to jQuery...

Answer (score -1):

<% ... %> does not like JavaScript.
Anyway:

```
'<%Session["showHideFlagValue"] = !(bool)Session["showHideFlagValue"]; %>';
```